# Spring Security OAuth2 Client (Shopify) error: tokenType cannot be null

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, shopify-api

I have a Spring Boot app in which I'm trying to call the Shopify API, authenticating via OAuth (https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/auth/oauth/getting-started) using the Spring Security OAuth2 Client library (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html).

I have made my way through the OAuth flow, but I've gotten stuck during the exchange of the authorization code to get the access token. The access token response from Shopify returns something like:

```json
{
  "access_token": "f85632530bf277ec9ac6f649fc327f17",
  "scope": "write_orders,read_customers"
}
```

And an exception is thrown from Spring Security: `tokenType cannot be null` from `OAuth2AccessToken` line 72.

I tried to see if I could customize this someway, but `OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType` is final and has a private Constructor with only one instance that is `Bearer`.

I assume Shopify doesn't consider this a `Bearer` token because rather than using it with an `Authentication` header, Shopify requires it to be used with a custom header `X-Shopify-Access-Token`.

The `OAuth2AccessToken` object is used by the `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken` used in `OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantFilter#processAuthorizationResponse`. This part of the code seem pretty integral to the Spring Security OAuth2 Client library, without a means of customization.

Is there a way to support this type of access token using Spring Security OAuth2 Client?

---

In an attempt to hack around the issue, I forced it to use `Bearer` token type, but I think this will only cause problems downstream as the library tries to handle this token as if it were a `Bearer` token.

```java
/**
 * Modified from DefaultMapOAuth2AccessTokenResponseConverter
 */
public class ShopifyAccessTokenResponseConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, OAuth2AccessTokenResponse> {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessTokenResponse convert(Map<String, Object> source) {
        String accessToken = getParameterValue(source, OAuth2ParameterNames.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType accessTokenType = OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER; // as if I had a choice
        Set<String> scopes = getScopes(source);
        String refreshToken = getParameterValue(source, OAuth2ParameterNames.REFRESH_TOKEN);
        return OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.withToken(accessToken)
                                        .tokenType(accessTokenType)
                                        .scopes(scopes)
                                        .refreshToken(refreshToken)
                                        .build();
    }

    private static Set<String> getScopes(Map<String, Object> tokenResponseParameters) {
        if (tokenResponseParameters.containsKey(OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE)) {
            String scope = getParameterValue(tokenResponseParameters, OAuth2ParameterNames.SCOPE);
            return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(StringUtils.delimitedListToStringArray(scope, " ")));
        }
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    private static String getParameterValue(Map<String, Object> tokenResponseParameters, String parameterName) {
        Object obj = tokenResponseParameters.get(parameterName);
        return (obj != null) ? obj.toString() : null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @dur . I didn't realize that tag was just for the deprecated library. I added the spring-security tag to replace it per the description.

Comment: Your approach seems fine. It's true that Spring Security requires a token type at this point, and perhaps that could be enhanced; however, I'm not understanding your concern about unexpected behavior. 

If all tokens in Spring Security must have BEARER, then it's not a differentiating characteristic of tokens at this point in the code. You should be able to assign a type of BEARER without issue. Have you seen any problems otherwise?